# How to stream H264 Video from camera over FTP?

Tags: webcam, vlc, ffmpeg, mplayer, video-streaming

I bought a h264 security camera system last year and set it up to ftp video to my computer.  I was able to get the video to play (even though it played a little fast) on Ubuntu 11.04 using mplayer.

A few months ago, I did a fresh install of 12.04 and I cannot seem to get the video to play with mplayer, smplayer or VLC.  I have the restricted formats video packages installed and when playing with any of the players, all I get is a gray video.

When calling mplayer from the command line to play the video with no options, I get a lot of these errors:

```
[h264 @ 0x7f278c61f280]concealing 1320 DC, 1320 AC, 1320 MV errors
No pts value from demuxer to use for frame!
pts after filters MISSING
```

I'm not a video expert and have been coming up with a lot of dead ends when Googling for this.  Could someone offer some advice about how to play these videos?

Here is the output of mediainfo for a sample file.

```
mediainfo -f sec-cam01-m-20120921-212454.h264
General
Count                                    : 278
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : General
Kind of stream                           : General
Stream identifier                        : 0
Count of video streams                   : 1
Video_Format_List                        : AVC
Video_Format_WithHint_List               : AVC
Codecs Video                             : AVC
Complete name                            : sec-cam01-m-20120921-212454.h264
File name                                : sec-cam01-m-20120921-212454
File extension                           : h264
Format                                   : AVC
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format/Url                               : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Format/Extensions usually used           : avc h264
Commercial name                          : AVC
Internet media type                      : video/H264
Codec                                    : AVC
Codec                                    : AVC
Codec/Info                               : Advanced Video Codec
Codec/Url                                : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Codec/Extensions usually used            : avc h264
File size                                : 1097315
File size                                : 1.05 MiB
File size                                : 1 MiB
File size                                : 1.0 MiB
File size                                : 1.05 MiB
File size                                : 1.046 MiB
File last modification date              : UTC 2012-09-22 01:27:12
File last modification date (local)      : 2012-09-21 21:27:12

Video
Count                                    : 205
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format/Url                               : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Commercial name                          : AVC
Format profile                           : Baseline@L4.0
Format settings                          : 1 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1
Format settings, ReFrames                : 1 frame
Format settings, GOP                     : M=1, N=3
Internet media type                      : video/H264
Codec                                    : AVC
Codec                                    : AVC
Codec/Family                             : AVC
Codec/Info                               : Advanced Video Codec
Codec/Url                                : http://developers.videolan.org/x264.html
Codec profile                            : Baseline@L4.0
Codec settings                           : 1 Ref Frames
Codec settings, CABAC                    : No
Codec_Settings_RefFrames                 : 1
Width                                    : 704
Width                                    : 704 pixels
Height                                   : 480
Height                                   : 480 pixels
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 1.000
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.467
Display aspect ratio                     : 3:2
Standard                                 : NTSC
Resolution                               : 8
Resolution                               : 8 bits
Colorimetry                              : 4:2:0
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Scan type                                : Progressive
Interlacement                            : PPF
Interlacement                            : Progressive
```

Edit: Here is a sample video using the same encoding: https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5acwzy8rtqn9xe/sec-cam08-m-20121118-105815.h264
(not the same video as mediainfo output)

Comment: Do you mind providing a downloadable sample for running some testing? Thank you.

Comment: A raw h264 stream is rather unusual for regular media players and may sometimes not provide all the necessary information needed for playback. Trying the latest `mmg` from the mkvtoolnix package with different settings might help getting a playable video file.

Comment: Here is a link to a sample video.  It's in the same format as the video info I posted before, but a different video.  Sorry about the lag time.   https://www.dropbox.com/s/l5acwzy8rtqn9xe/sec-cam08-m-20121118-105815.h264

Comment: I am leaving this comment in order to follow up this later. Thank you for the sample. BBL